# Mini split whirring sound

Tags: mini-split

I recently had a new cooling only 12K inverter mini split installed in my bedroom which I run 24/7 on low fan speed.  The unit is very quiet and I am generally pleased with it.  However I have noticed that it makes a whirring sound every few hours that I don't understand.  The whirring sound typically lasts about 45 to 60 seconds building in pitch until it hits a peak, and then the whirring noise steadily dissipates in the next 45 to 60 seconds until the unit reverts back to relative silence again.  By monitoring the circuit load with an Amprobe, I have been able to determine that the whirring noise that I am hearing is apparently the compressor starting up.  It typically begins when there is very little load on the unit - less than 1 amp.  Then over the next 45 to 60 seconds the amperage steadily increases as the whirring sound increases in pitch until it hits a peak of about 3.6 amps.  Then over the following 45 to 60 seconds the load steadily decreases to 1 amp or less as the whirring noise decreases.  I thought the whole purpose of an inverter unit was to create a steady and uniform electrical load on the compressor.  Do the capacitors need occasional charging, or can anybody explain what is happening here?

Comment: Are you in heat mode?

Comment: Sounds like a defrost cycle.

Comment: Yeah, what mode do you have your unit set to?  Also, is there water dripping out the bottom of the outdoor unit (compressor unit)?

Comment: As stated in my post, this is a cooling only unit.  Thus there is no heating mode or defrost cycle.  The unit is set on cooling mode.

Comment: Well I missed cooling only, what is the brand? model? Something that only happens every few hours sounds unusual and don’t jump to capacitors. How old is the unit? Is this a wired or remote controlled unit (some remotes connect with a temp change and that connection could be the change).

Comment: The unit is a TGM model #MRGFDT12AS  and it was installed new about a month ago. https://www.refripartes.com.do/uploads/MWGFDTSpecs.pptx%20(1)%20.pdf .  I am in the Dominican Republic and TGM seems to have a stranglehold on the market here.  It is difficult to say how many times per day that I hear the wind up and wind down whirring noise because I don't really notice if I am not in the bedroom where the unit is installed or if the TV is on.  Most of the time when I notice it is when I am on my bed when I wake up in the morning or if I am laying on my bed during the day watching TV.

Comment: I don't know if it happens every time that the compressor speed increases, but it seems to occur when the unit is under low load (as measured by my amprobe) and then there is an apparent demand from the controls for more cooling power.  My best guess is that it is occurring every few hours multiple times per day.  My amprobe registers the same pattern each time that it occurs:  there is a steady increase in amperage as the pitch of the noise increases, and then a steady decrease in amperage as the whirring noise decreases.

Comment: The unit is controlled with an infrared remote that I have set to cooling mode and low fan speed 24/7.